# Reuse the same popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am looking to use the same pop up window each time the pop up is called. Actually I need to do a form submit into a pop-up window, it is working fine, but in Chrome iOS each time I submit the form it opens a new tab/window instead use the previous one.

To resume what I want I did this jsfiddle:  Each time that you click the submit button you will see a new pop-up window is opened instead use the previous opened window.

http://jsfiddle.net/s5ph2rzy/

```
<input type="submit" onclick="mainVar.setFormSubmit();" value="Submit" />
var mainVar = {
    setFormSubmit: function() {
       window.open('', 'formtarget','width=650, height=800');
    }
}
```

I have found out info saying to use the same popup name, but it does not work. Also I found out this page where it explains how to do this http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4PYJ3S?OpenDocument but it does not work in my jsfiddle neither. Can you help me to uptate my jsfiddle with a workable code?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reuse your window's name. In your example, you've named the window as "formtarget".

You can do this, for example:

```
var popupWin = null;
var mainVar = {
    setFormSubmit: function() {
       popupWin = window.open('', 'formtarget','width=650, height=800');
    }
}

function openAnotherLink(url) {
     popupWin.location.href = url;
}
```